# SQLite index usage with different type affinity

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple table "tags" containing a key and a value column. The key is always a string, the value can be either string, int64 or a double value.

I do not have any real data at this point to test with. But I'm curious about the index usage of the value column. I've defined the column as TEXT type - is SQLite still able to use the index on the value column when an int64 or double type is bound to the statement?

Here is the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE "tags" ("key" TEXT,"value" TEXT DEFAULT (null) );
INSERT INTO "tags" VALUES('test','test');
INSERT INTO "tags" VALUES('testint','1');
INSERT INTO "tags" VALUES('testdouble','2.0');
```

I see additional "Integer" and "Affinity" entries when analyzing the query via:

```
explain SELECT value FROM tags where key = "testint" and value >= 1
```

But I do not see any difference in index usage otherwise (e.g. idxgt is always used). But I'd rather like to have a definite answer rather than relying on wrong assumption with the small test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) says:

> A column with TEXT affinity stores all data using storage classes NULL, TEXT or BLOB. If numerical data is inserted into a column with TEXT affinity it is converted into text form before being stored.

The sort order is [well-defined](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons) for all types.
Forcing the affinity to be TEXT makes comparisons on this column with numbers behave as if the values were text, but that is probably what you want.

In any case, indexes do not change the behaviour; they work correctly with all types, and apply affinities in exactly the same way as on non-indexed columns.

Comment: What I probably was not clear enough about: Besides that I store numeric values, and which you correctly state get converted to text when storing, I in fact need to query for numeric *and* text values. A text index would order the following strings in this way: "1", "20", "3". A numeric index would order it 1, 3 20. Though the question still remains, whether SQLite will still be partially make use of an index when say "querying for integers values with integers stored in a text column.". The obvious workaround would be to use three fields for each type - but I'd rather avoid it if I can.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question I asked, though there is a catch in my case (I didn't mention the need to order the result in my question): One needs to cast the value to integer to get a numerical order - which can be expensive when there are many big numbers between in the result set. And this also requires the use of external sort and storage. For example the following is more expensive due to required external sort and seek between reults: explain SELECT value FROM tags where key = "test" and value >= 1 order by cast(value as integer)

Comment: The fastest index for this particular query would be a covering [expression index](http://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html): `create index tkviv on tags(key, cast(value as integer), value);`.